# (<T>(x: any): x is T[] => x && typeof x.length === 'number')

Tags: typescript

I just came across this line of code which checks if a variable is an array:

```
export const isArray = Array.isArray || (<T>(x: any): x is T[] => x && typeof x.length === 'number');

isArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I'm really confused about how to make sense of `(<T>(x: any): x is T[] => x && typeof x.length === 'number')`. How to understand the casting and the expression?

Note that I come from a JavaScript background so I understand `Array.isArray` and the `x.length` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<T>(x: any): x is T[]` - This is the signature of the function. The function is generic (`<T>`) with an `any` parameter. This function signature is also a type guard, meaning it influences the type of the parameter after a call, namely the type of `x` will be `T[]` if `isArray` returns true (`x is T[]`) so

```
const isArray = (<T>(x: any): x is T[] => x && typeof x.length === 'number');
let x: any;
if(isArray<number>(x)) {
    console.log(x[0]) // x is an array
}
```

The next part is the body of the function, and it just checks that `length` exists and is a `number`

```
x && typeof x.length === 'number'
```

**Note**

The signature of `Array.isArray` is not the same as the signature of the replacement (`<T>(x: any): x is T[]`). To allow `isArray` usage as a type guard i would suggest changing the declaration to:

```
export const isArray  = Array.isArray as (<T>(x: any) => x is T[]) 
    || (<T>(x: any): x is T[] => x && typeof x.length === 'number');
```

Answer (score 0):

The type expression

```
x is T[]
```

is called [user defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) in TypeScript. Essentially it gives a hint to the type checker such that if the function call `isArray(x)` returns true, the type of x will be narrowed to `T[]`